# Multiple Viewport OpenGL ES

Tags: ios, opengl-es, viewport

I am currently trying to make an ios app that uses multiple opengl es viewports (i.e. a split screen). Here's how I'm doing it:

```
// Create default framebuffer object. The backing will be allocated for the current layer in -resizeFromLayer
    glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &defaultFramebuffer);
    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &colorRenderbuffer);
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, defaultFramebuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);

// Replace the implementation of this method to do your own custom drawing
const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
  -0.5f, -0.5f,
  0.5f,  -0.5f,
  -0.5f,  0.5f,
  0.5f,   0.5f,
};
const GLubyte squareColors[] = {
  255, 255,   0, 255,
  0,   255, 255, 255,
  0,     0,   0,   0,
  255,   0, 255, 255,
 };

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, defaultFramebuffer);
glViewport(0, backingHeight/2, backingWidth/2, backingHeight/2);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrthof(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.5f, 1.5f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glRotatef(3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, squareVertices);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, squareColors);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);
// equivalent to glutswapBuffers()
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];

/*********************SECOND VIEW*******/
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, defaultFramebuffer);
glViewport(backingWidth/2, 0, backingWidth/2, backingHeight/2);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrthof(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.5f, 1.5f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glRotatef(3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, squareVertices);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, squareColors);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
/*********************END***************/

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

1. On the simulator, only the second viewport appears (in this case a rotating cube in the bottom right corner of screen). Whereas on the device they both appear but blinking... (top left AND bottom riht)
2. the glRotatef gets applied twice, but I only want to or any other transformation to be applied once.

What i want is simply to show the same scene twice. Basically I'm trying to simulate having 2 cameras watching the same thing, and show this on the screen. Clearly, I'm doing something wrong, would it be better to have 2 separate framebuffers and renderbuffers or is there a simpler way of achieving this?

Comment: Do you do any glGetError checking?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
/*********************SECOND VIEW*******/
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
```

glClear is not affected by the viewport, you need to use either the scissors test or the stencil buffer if you want to partially clear.

See the documentation for [glClear](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClear.xml).

Comment: commenting that line out does not change anything, same effect